# Javascript: Input bar isn't working or giving any result

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I made a program that asks the user how many input bars he wants to display and then the user has to type in some values into the input bars and click verify but the issue i am having is that whenever i click on verify, nothing happens. I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

whenever i click on verify.

Here are my codes:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      var x = [];
      var choose;
      var i;
      var xar=[];
      choose=parseFloat(prompt("how many inputs u want to display"));
      for(i=0;i<choose;i++)
        x[i]=document.getElementById("cont"+i).style.visibility="visible";

      function hola() {
        for(i=0;i<choose;i++)
          document.getElementById("cont"+i).style.visibility="visible";

      }


      function verify(){
        for(i=0;i<choose;i++){
          xar[i]=document.getElementById("userNumber"+i).value;
        }
        for(i=0;i<choose;i++)
          if(xar[i]==i)
            alert("good");
          else
            alert("wrong");
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield0" id="boton0">

    <div id="cont0" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <input type="text" id="userNumber" class="something">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield2" id="boton1">
    <div id="cont1" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="username2">
    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield1" id="boton2">

    <div id="cont2" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="username3">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield3" id="boton3">

    <div id="cont3" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="username4">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield4" id="boton4">

    <div id="cont4" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="username5">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield5" id="boton5">

    <div id="cont5" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="username6">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="verify()">
  </body>
  <html>
```

Comment: Is there any html that you are using?

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to put it in.. Hang on i will do it

Comment: @Shniper i included the html :) Thank u for helping btw. What do u think i did wrong in the codes? :/

Comment: What is it that you want to be done with the values in the input bar when the user clicks verify?

Comment: @Shniper Well i want the values typed in by the user to be compared with the pre-defined values and if the user is right, it says good if not, he loses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is failing when it reaches this portion:

```
 document.getElementById("userNumber"+i)
```

This indicates that there is no element called `userNumber + i` (i.e. "userNumber3") for you to then call the `.value` property of (*Cannot read property 'value' of null*) .

And that's because you have elements with ids of "***username2, username3, username4, etc.***" and "**userNumber**", but not "userNumber" plus a number.

```js
      var x = [];
      var choose;
      var i;
      var xar=[];
      choose=parseFloat(prompt("how many inputs u want to display"));
      for(i=0;i<choose;i++)
        x[i]=document.getElementById("cont"+i).style.visibility="visible";

      function hola() {
        for(i=0;i<choose;i++)
          document.getElementById("cont"+i).style.visibility="visible";

      }


      function verify(){
        for(i=0;i<choose;i++){
          xar[i]=document.getElementById("userNumber"+i).value;
        }
        for(i=0;i<choose;i++)
          if(xar[i]==i)
            alert("good");
          else
            alert("wrong");
      }
```

```html
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield0" id="boton0">

    <div id="cont0" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <input type="text" id="userNumber" class="something">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield2" id="boton1">
    <div id="cont1" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="userNumber2">
    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield1" id="boton2">

    <div id="cont2" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="userNumber3">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield3" id="boton3">

    <div id="cont3" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="userNumber4">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield4" id="boton4">

    <div id="cont4" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="userNumber5">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="hola()" value="hidefield5" id="boton5">

    <div id="cont5" style="visibility: hidden;" class="something">
      <input type="text" id="userNumber6">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="verify()">
```

Comment: but how can i add "UserName" + a number with input tags :/

Comment: btw thank u for trying to help me out. Really appreciate it

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers "add" them where? Just change the HTML so that the elements aren't called `username2`, etc. and are instead named `userNumber2`, etc.

Comment: same thing happened.. Clicked on verify and nothing happened.. Checked the errors but was the same Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers It works when I make that change. See the code snipped in my updated answer.

Comment: i tried running ur code but i am still getting the same problem :/ clicking on verify didn't do anything. Just showed errors :/

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers You just clicked the blue "Run code snippet" button at the bottom of my answer?  I don't think so.

Comment: I did. And then i even copied the codes into my program to check if it runs properly but i am still getting the same error. Clicking on verify isn't showing me an alert message at all :/

Comment: Ah ok i got what the error was..In html, UserName is starting for 1 but in javascript its starting from 0. Now it works thanks

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers  Don't forget to mark as the answer. Good luck!